# Microsoft Code Contracts and CI build server

Tags: c#, .net, continuous-integration, teamcity, code-contracts

We are migrating to .NET 4 and very interested in implementing new Design By Contract capabilities.

As we know [Code Contract](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) engine requires installation of [Code Contract addin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx)
[image]
and VS Ultimate or Premium (for static checking).

Here is my questions:

1. Can I use code contract rewriting
   without installing VS on CI build Server (TeamCity)?
2. Is there any
   msbuild tasks to execute Contract checking?
3. Do you use Code Contract's validation with CI builds?

Comment: I would love to get code contract static analysis for at least nightly builds, so I'll be interested to hear what people have to say.  It would also be very cool if there was a server-side static analysis service so that you could set up a very fast server and let it host static analysis, rather than having it slowly churn away on the development machine.  Maybe even a static analysis cloud service?

Comment: @Dan I played a little with Code Contract's static analysis and it is pretty cool. Now trying to set up TeamCity build ... Here is msbuild integration info (page 41) http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf

Comment: I like the idea of a static analysis cloud service. Hrrmmmm...maybe I should try building this.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844242/c-sharp-unit-testing-integrate-nunit-mbunit-with-microsoft-pex which outlines some of the steps.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> Can I use code contract rewriting without installing VS on CI build
>   server (TeamCity)?

Yes. Install CodeContracts on the build server. (If it refuses to install on a machine without Visual Studio, just copy the files listed below, and their dependencies, onto the build server.) Once installed, you'll find the CodeContract tools installed in %programfiles%\Microsoft\Contracts\Bin. In that directory, there are 4 executables you'll be interested in:

1. ccrewrite.exe - The binary rewriter. This should be executed after compilation. It turns your contracts into runtime checks or whatever you specify you want them turned into.
2. ccrefgen.exe - This can generate contract reference assemblies alongside your assemblies. This is useful if you're shipping dlls to be consumed by other parties.
3. cccheck.exe - The static checker. On the build server, you'd run this tool over your assemblies containing contracts, and it will spit out warnings and messages as it encounters potential problems.
4. ccdocgen.exe - This generates XML documentation from the contracts in your code. You might want to use this if you're shipping dlls with contracts for consumption by other parties, or if you just need internal docs on your code.

> Is there any msbuild tasks to execute Contract checking?

Yes. There are 2 MSBuild tasks shipping with CodeContracts: in the same CodeContracts installation directory, check out the MSBuild\[framework version] folder. In that directory, there are 2 files that should help you out: Microsoft.CodeContracts.targets and Microsoft.CodeContractAnalysis.targets.

According to the CodeContracts documentation,

> An msbuild script extension Microsoft
>   .Contract. targets contains the extra
>   build actions for the runtime contract
>   instrumentation and static verification
>   steps. As a result of this approach,
>   it is possible to use the same
>   functionality when building from the
>   command line with the msbuild command.
>   Using msbuild on a project or solution
>   that uses contracts enabled via the VS
>   user interface will perform the same
>   actions as the corresponding build
>   under VS.

As you can see, it is possible and supported to integrate the tools into CI builds via the MSBuild targets.

> Do you use Code Contract's validation with CI builds?

Assuming you mean static checking with warnings/messages, I've done this personally, but haven't done this on a big project.

I hope this helps!

Hat tip to Jon Skeet's [C# In Depth](http://www.manning.com/skeet2/) book for explanation of the command line tools.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now we are trying to set this up in TeamCity.

Comment: Cool. Please let me know the result!

Comment: Note: code contracts are no longer covered in C# In Depth book (as of third edition)